# How to specify custom string for NULL values in Hive table stored as text?

Tags: hadoop, serialization, hive, format

When storing Hive table in text format, for example this table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE clustered_item_info
  (
    country_id              int,
    item_id                 string,
    productgroup            int,
    category                string
  )
  PARTITIONED BY (cluster_id int)
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
  LOCATION '${hivevar:table_location}';
```

**Fields with null values are represented as '\N' strings, also for numbers NaNs are represented as 'NaN' strings.**

**Does Hive provide a way to specify custom string to represent these special values?**

I would like to use empty strings instead of '\N' and 0 instead of 'NaN' - I know this substitution can be done with streaming, but is there any way to it cleanly using Hive instead of writing extra code?

Other info:
I'm using Hive 0.8 if that matters...

Answer (score 4):

Use this property while creating the table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS abc
(
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
TBLPROPERTIES ("serialization.null.format"="")

Answer (score 2):

oh, sorry. I read your question not clear

If you want to represented empty string instead of '\N', you can using [COALESCE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-ConditionalFunctions) function:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3://bucket/result/' 
SELECT NULL, COALESCE(NULL,"")
FROM data_table;
```

Comment: dont see how this adressed null problem in my questoion